# How to get anchor to change color when I toggle the body background-color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, anchor

I've created a light/dark mode button with an onClick function that runs an element.classList.toggle.

The CSS class I toggle to is connected to `document.body` and changes the `background-color` and `color`.

However, I've struggling to find a way to include the `<a>` anchor links so that they also toggle to white/black text along with the `document.body` toggle.

When I use the code below, I can only change the text and background color of the body and text. Not including the  anchor links in my HTML file.

How do I set the anchor tags to start as black color text when in light mode, and switch with the `onclick` function to white color text when the rest of the page turns to dark mode?

```js
function myFunction() {
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="lightDark">Dark Mode</button>

<a id="contact" class="links" href="mailto: abc@protonmail.com">contact</a>
<a id="resume" class="links" href="/abc.pdf" target="_blank">resume</a>
```

Comment: background of the links changes ... links don't start black on white, so why would they become white on black?

Comment: `a {background:#fff; color: #000;} .dark-mode a {background: #000; color: #fff}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `>` to select the direct children in css

```js
function myFunction() {
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode>a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="lightDark">Dark Mode</button>

<a id="contact" class="links" href="mailto: abc@protonmail.com">contact</a>
<a id="resume" class="links" href="/abc.pdf" target="_blank">resume</a>
```

You can skip `>` if you intend to select all anchors

```js
function myFunction() {
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="lightDark">Dark Mode</button>


<div>
  <a id="contact" class="links" href="mailto: abc@protonmail.com">contact</a>
  <a id="resume" class="links" href="/abc.pdf" target="_blank">resume</a>

  <div>

    <a id="contact" class="links" href="mailto: abc@protonmail.com">Test 1</a>
    <a id="resume" class="links" href="/abc.pdf" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: dont use the `>` direct child selector. Anchors will not necessarily be a direct child of body.

Comment: why would you limit it to just direct children of the body?

Comment: The answer is based on the user's criteria

Comment: there are no specific criteria mentioned by the OP that only direct children to the body should be affected. a [repro]  is not a guarantee of the actual markup but a minimalistic code example